# Error when adding custom options

Tags: magento2.2

I am facing an issue with customizable options. 
When I add a custom option to a product, I receive an error on the product page:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in web/.../public_html/app/design/frontend/../Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml on line 53
```

Here is the form.phtml code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Neoxero. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
 */
?>

<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //  print_r( $block->getJsonConfig()); ?>

<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>

    <form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post"
          id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_top'); ?>
        <?php if (!$block->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php // echo $block->getChildHtml('product_info_form_content'); ?>
        <?php else:?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container1'):?>
                <?php echo $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container2'):?>
            <?php echo $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product_cart_wish_compare'); ?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_bottom'); ?>
    </form>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'
    ], function($){
        var priceBoxes = $('.catalog-product-view [data-role=priceBox],.modal-dialog [data-role=priceBox]');

        priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
            return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
        });

        priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestion to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are getting array  "echo $block->getJsonConfig()" here. But you have print as a string. So Please print first and check.